# Error inflating class AppCompatButton

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-appcompat

I am making project and requirement is User Interface is same for all android device.For achieve this requirement I googled and I got the solution to use newly AppCompact Library for same UI in all Android version.

So Question is for, There is one button in my Layout and I use **AppCompatButton** instead of **Button**.

Even my Activity for that Layout extends AppCompatActivity.
But when I run that project I get below error and app goes crash.

Here is my code for Activity and Layout

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     AppCompatButton appCompatButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
     appCompatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
  }
 }
```

Layout :

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                   
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.app.myway.MainActivity">

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/et_email"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
         android:hint="@string/add_email"
         android:paddingLeft="16dp"
         android:paddingRight="16dp" />

   <AppCompatButton
         android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/submit" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.myway/com.app.myway.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class AppCompatButton
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/submit" />
```

and in your build.gradle:

```
 dependencies{
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
 }
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton... works